# How do I handle huge data on frontend, without processing pagination on server side using pug in frontend?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datatables, pug

I have 20 columns. I have totals to be shown, at the end of the table similar to below:

```
No  Deb stc Vehicle     Dest        bg  T
1   ABC PQR MH02A12345  KANDIVALI   100 5.00
2   ABC PQR MH02A12346  KANDIVALI   50  2.50
3   ABC PQR MH02A12347  GOREGAON    200 10.00
4   ABC PQR MH02A12348  DIVA        200 10.00
5   ABC PQR MH02A12349  JOGESHWARI  100 5.00
6   ABC PQR MH02A12350  ANDHERI     100 5.00
7   ABC PQR MH02A12351  VIKHROLI    150 7.50
8   ABC PQR MH02A12352  BORIVALI    400 20.50
9   ABC PQR MH02A12353  KAMOTHE     200 10.00
10  ABC PQR MH02A12354  MIRA ROAD   200 10.00
            Grand Total            1700 85.5
```

Results achieved are more than 100k. When I am using datatable it takes a long time to display. How can I process all the data on server side at once and then send result chunk by chunk but with actual totals?

I cannot do server side processing I am using node.js, mongodb and pug.

Comment: Please rewrite the last statement as it contradicts itself.
_How can I process all the data on **server side** at once and then send result chunk by chunk but with actual totals? I cannot do **server side** processing..._

Comment: @GibinEalias Sorry for the confusion but what I meant was that i will process all the data at once on server side without paginating it and then send the result in frontend where the display will be done part by part.As for me results processing(server side) is not taking too long but displaying and rendering it on frontend is taking longer time.

Comment: Seems like your best bet would be to have the initial 20 items or so show up on first page render, and then you can just AJAX for the rest in one call -- because you do not want to have to deal with pagination.